# Json file to Room Db

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-room

I am a newbie on Android Development.I have a json file formatted like this:

```
"users": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Vanessa",
    "profilepic": "https://.."
  },...
]
```

I am creating room database but how can I record this user json file into it. I heard about gson but I could not find any solution for my problem

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to first create a model that can parse this kind of json for you. you can use a pretty neat plugin that I have been sing called json to kotlin class.
Steps to install:

1. Go to file->settings->plugins
2. search for json to kotlin and install
3. now just like you make a new file there will be a new option paste your json and give it a name and now it automatically generates a model for you.
4. Also I will recommend you to watch some tutorials on youtube, my favorite content creator is Philip Lackener he has a very good tutorial on roomdb

I am also new to android development so i get it.
I recommend you to go through a beginner playlist it will really help you get the basics. you also need to see basics of roomdb because what you are asking is really basics of roomdb.